# I couldnt solve it. Someone would help me?

Tags: power

[image]

If someone share solution A and B I'd be appreciate...

Comment: Show your work so far and then explain where you got stuck.  Otherwise you are just asking people to help you cheat on yourhomework.

Comment: Chose the -ve terminal at bottom as GND and 0V. YOu have the value of U and voltages across Z2 and Z4. From this you now have voltage at every node. Start doing nodal analysis and solving.

Comment: I removed your request to email the responses. That's not how this web site works.

Comment: I dont even know how tis web site works. I just created account yesterday.Sorry bout e mail responses. @DoxyLover

Comment: I dont know how to solve it. I dont know where I should begin. That's why I posted it @user1850479

Comment: @muro This is not a first year's training site. And it's not a free homework solving site. I promise you, if we provided a solution here, you wouldn't understand it, because you did not learn it the hard way. What sample calculations did you receive from your professor?

Answer (score 1):

it would be Kirchhoff's Mesh Current Method with complex numbers matrices

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. While your answer may be technically correct, it won't be much of a help for the OP. In general, most single line answers are considered insufficient here, because we like to leverage more usage for later readers.

Comment: i'm no a substituting teacher here, fortunately.  The complexity of explanation possible to observe here:  https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-circuit-analysis-topic/ee-dc-circuit-analysis/a/ee-mesh-current-method